# CakePHP and jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: cakephp

I am working with CakePHP. What I need in my application is autosuggestion. I used following code to achieve my goal:

```
jQuery("#name").autocomplete( '<?php echo HTTP_PATH.'songs/sss'; ?>', {
    multiple: true,
    mustMatch: true,        
    matchContains: true,
    autoFill: false,
});
```

Sending my request to the `SongsController`' `sss` function... My controller function is:

```
public function sss(){
    $this->layout = '';
    $condition = '';
    $condition = array('Poet.status'=>'3');
    $poet_name = $this->Poet->find('list', array('conditions' => $condition));
    return $poet_name;
}
```

First issue is that I am returning my result in array. How would I separate my result again in a suggestion list.

Second thing is that when I tried to check the response using the Firebug panel, I noticed that CakePHP is expecting a view at this point. I don't want any sort of view as I am not updating anything...

Comment: You should really look into [`json_encode`](http://ca3.php.net/json_encode). What version of CakePHP are you using? CakePHP 2 has a [`JsonView`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) class which you could use for this purpose too.

Comment: I am new with cakephp... Can u please help me with this Jsonview. Caking PHP is expecting for view as I checked response but I am not rendering any view. Please help...

Comment: Are you using CakePHP 2.1? Because that view wasn't available in earlier versions. The documentation is quite good at explaining everything you have to do. You should follow the instructions.

Comment: I am using cake2.0.... Suppose I send data as `return json_encode($poet_name;)` then... How to make it available in JS funcion as suggestion list.

Comment: Its expecting view as its giving error of missing view

Comment: Set `$this->autoRender = false;` and that'll fix the problem with it requiring a view. You should also change the `return json_encode($poet_name;)` to `echo json_encode($poet_name);`.

Comment: OK Please help me to decode json... How can I decode it with above code. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out serializing you data as JSON: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key. By setting a `_serialize` variable in the view you are telling Cake what data is important when it gets a request for a data view.

You will also need to add `Router::parseExtensions('json');` and a `.json` to the end of your URI in the jQuery call so that Cake knows to respond with a JSON data view and use the data in the `_serialize` key you set like I mentioned above. There more info on file extensions here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions

Here's how I would write the method:

```
public function sss(){
    $this->layout = '';
    $condition = array('Poet.status'=>'3');
    $poets = $this->Poet->find('list', array('conditions' => $condition));
    $this->set(compact('poets'));
    $this->set('_serialize', $poets);
}
```